# Get email address from SecurityContextHolder spring java MVC

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, log4j2

I am using log4j framework. I want to insert logged in user's email address into the database. I am using this:

```
UserDetails origUser = (UserDetails)securityContext.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

The object has methods below :

```
origUser.getUsername(),
origUser.isEnabled(),
origUser.isAccountNonExpired(),
origUser.isCredentialsNonExpired(),
origUser.isAccountNonLocked(),
origUser.getAuthorities());
```

But none of the methods returns email address. How can I retrieve user email information so that I can use it like :

```
MDC.put("username",origUser.getEmail());
```

log4j.properties has

```
log4j.appender.DB.sql=INSERT INTO LOGS VALUES('%X{username}','%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}','%C','%p','%m')
```

Answer (score 1):

`UserDetails` `getUsername` method returns the String which was used for authenticating the user. This is primarily the identifier with which you lookup in the datastore to check the existence of user, match the password for authentication and load it's granted roles/authorities to check its authorization. If this was email ( say a combination of email/password) used for authentication, then this should return the email, else it should return the identifier whatever was used for purpose of authentication.

Comment: getUserName() returning the UserName. One possible solution is I can maintain a global hashmap of UserName and UserEmail. So if I want emailId in other pages, I will simply get the value using UserName key.